# Inverse of x^x?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

What is the inverse of $y = x^x$? I know it won't be in terms of elementary functions, but I believe some function analogous to Lambert W function for $z = ye^y$ would be defined? I couldn't find it on google.

Comment: [When in doubt, ask Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+x%5Ex).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Lambert-$W$:
$$y^{-1}(x)=e^{W(\log x)} = \frac{\log x}{W( \log x)}$$

Proof:
\begin{align*}
y=x^x &\iff \log y=x\log x\\
&\iff \log y=e^{\log x}\log x\\
&\iff W(\log y)=\log x\\
&\iff x=e^{W(\log y)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think a proof (which is not hard at all) would make this a great answer.

Comment: @DonThousand I'll edit my answer